Issue about converting C++ to MIPS
I'm a college student and the MIPS code I'm trying to turn in does not get printed out. My assignment is converting C++ to MIPS. I converted C++ code to MIPS but it doesn't print out the right answer(25, 109, 321). I have only about 5 hours left until my assignment is due, and I have no idea what else to do. Could you please tell me why my code doesn't print out the correct result(25, 109, 321)? And I know it's not the right thing to ask here but it would be so great if you give MIPS code as well. I'm using Mars4_5.jar for my MIPS. It makes (.asm file)
C++ Code
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int poly(int);
int pow(int, int);

int main() {
  int i;
  int result;

  for (i=2; i<=4; i++) {
    result = poly(i);
    cout << result << endl;
  }
}

int poly(int arg) {
  int temp1, result;
  temp1 = pow(arg, 4);
  result = pow(arg, 3);
  result = temp1 + result + 1;
  return result;
}

int pow(int arg0, int arg1) {
  int product = 1;
  for (int i=0; i<arg1; i++) {
    product *= arg0;
  }
  return product;
}

MIPS Code
.data
newline: .asciiz "\n"

.text
.globl main

main:
    
    li $t0, 2          
    li $t1, 4          

loop:
    
    bgt $t0, $t1, end  

    move $a0, $t0      
    jal poly           

    
    move $a0, $v0      
    li $v0, 1           
    syscall           

    
    li $v0, 4          
    la $a0, newline    
    syscall           

    addi $t0, $t0, 1  
    j loop             

end:
    li $v0, 10         
    syscall           

poly:
    addi $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $ra, 8($sp)
    sw $s0, 4($sp)

    move $s0, $a0

    move $a0, $s0
    li $a1, 4
    jal pow
    move $s1, $v0     

    move $a0, $s0
    li $a1, 3
    jal pow

    add $v0, $s1, $v0
    addi $v0, $v0, 1

    lw $ra, 8($sp)
    lw $s0, 4($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 12
    jr $ra

pow:
    addi $sp, $sp, -8
    sw $ra, 4($sp)
    sw $s0, 0($sp)

    li $s0, 1          

loop_pow:
    bge $a1, $zero, exit_pow  
    mul $s0, $s0, $a0   
    addi $a1, $a1, -1   
    j loop_pow          

exit_pow:
    move $v0, $s0       

    lw $ra, 4($sp)
    lw $s0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 8
    jr $ra


It does print here. Admittedly the wrong result, but it does get printed :)

Oh you are right. Thank you for pointing out. Based on the given C++ code, the answer should be 25, 109, 321. Could you give me a hand and tell me which part I did wrong?

Are you allowed to use a compiler? https://godbolt.org/z/eeen7zGcx

I tried to use that website, but it doesn't seem like it fits to my program. I'm using Mars4_5.jar. It gave me a long bunch of code that's similar with my MIPS code, but Mars4_5.jar said there are lots of errors.

bge $a1, $zero, exit_pow is definitely wrong as that will exit immediately. You are lucky, that seems to be the only problem. Turning that into ble seems to fix it. PS: next time use your simulator to single step the code to find where it does something unexpected.

All right. Thank you for telling me the good compiler website and advice!

Thank you so so so so so much Mr. Jester. Without your help, I would had to stay awake the whole night and go to class. Words can't express how grateful I am for your advice. It means soooooooo big to me. God bless you and hope you have nothing but the best!

Fyi, the pow function can be coded without using a stack frame - no need to save $ra as nothing that function does alters it. Instead of using $s0 you can use $v0.  With these there's no longer need for stack use.
